# Blazor - Identity Register page Custom File Input not working

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

Within a Blazor web app (.Net 8) I have scaffolded identity and added a few custom properties: first name, last name and profile pic.
The first name and last name work but profile pic doesn't. Every time I upload the form and click the register button the input field clears and I get validation errors and I don't know why.

This is the inputModel:

```
private sealed class InputModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Profile Pic")]
    public IFormFile ProfilePictureBase64 { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; } = "";
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; } = "";

    ...Rest of properties
}
```

The form where I make the input file:

```
<EditForm Model="Input" asp-route-returnUrl="@ReturnUrl" method="post" OnValidSubmit="RegisterUser" FormName="register">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <ValidationSummary class="text-danger" role="alert" />
    <div class="form-floating mb-3">
        <InputFile @bind-Value="Input.ProfilePictureBase64" class="form-control" autocomplete="username" aria-required="true" placeholder="name@example.com" />
        <label for="firstName">Profile Pic</label>
        <ValidationMessage For="() => Input.ProfilePictureBase64" class="text-danger" />
    </div>

...Rest of Form
```

For some reason, the image gets reset if anyone knows why.

Update, I have changed it to this and it still doesn't work:
Form Input:

```
   <EditForm Model="Input" asp-route-returnUrl="@ReturnUrl" method="post" OnValidSubmit="RegisterUser" FormName="register">
       <DataAnnotationsValidator />
       <ValidationSummary class="text-danger" role="alert" />
       <div class="form-floating mb-3">
           <InputFile OnChange="@HandleFileSelection" class="form-control" aria-required="true" />
           <label for="firstName">Profile Pic</label>
           <ValidationMessage For="() => Input.ProfilePicture" class="text-danger" />
       </div>
...rest of form
```

Function:

```
    private async Task HandleFileSelection(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        var file = e.GetMultipleFiles().FirstOrDefault();
        if (file != null)
        {
            var buffer = new byte[file.Size];
            using (var stream = file.OpenReadStream())
            {
                await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            }
            var base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(buffer);
            Input.ProfilePicture = base64String;            
        }
    }
```

Model:

```
private sealed class InputModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Profile Pic")]
    public string ProfilePicture { get; set; }
...rest of model
```

Comment: Have you verified with the debugger or a logger that you have the value you are expecting after  `var base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(buffer);`?

Comment: i just have. I added a breakpoint at the function that changes the image to a base 64 string. But the breakpoint never runs for some reason.

Comment: does the onChange never run because the Blazor register is only SSR?

Answer (score 2):

Unlike the [`InputText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.forms.inputtext?view=aspnetcore-8.0) component, [`InputFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.forms.inputfile?view=aspnetcore-8.0) has no `Value` property so `@bind-Value` doesn't do anything. You need to pass a callback to the `OnChange` property that accepts a parameter of type `InputFileChangeEventArgs`:

```cs
<InputFile OnChange="@LoadFiles" multiple />

@code {
    private void LoadFiles(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        // Do something with the file upload here 
        //  (e.File or e.GetMultipleFiles()).
    }
}
```

Here is the documentation for this component: [Blazor File Uploads - Server-side Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-8.0#server-side-file-upload-example).

Comment: thanks for the info, but i updated my code and it still doesnt work. Do you know why?

Comment: I also tried to remove the [Required] but when i check my db the ProfilePic cell is empty